# What is ε in differential privacy?

Tags: terminology, differential-privacy

In ε-differential privacy, what does the ε refer to?

Is it privacy value or the notation used?

Can anyone provide an example of differential privacy?

Comment: providing links to papers where you read this, with some context quoted from the paper inline in your question would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In ε-differential privacy, **`ε` represents the privacy parameter**.

You might want to try to enhance your research efforts because related papers and publications mention that more than frequently.

Even websites like Wikipedia would have quickly provided you with an answer to your question. Quoting [Wikipedia > Differential privacy > ε-differential privacy > Trade-off between utility and privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_privacy#Trade-off_between_utility_and_privacy):

> A trade-off between the accuracy of the statistics estimated in a privacy-preserving manner, and **the privacy parameter ε.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Beyond that, you could also take a good look at these [Google scholar search results](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=%22%CE%B5-differential+privacy%22+%2B+%22privacy+parameter+%CE%B5%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5). The truckloads of related papers and publications presented there explain ε-differential privacy and tend to contain examples. Honestly, “simply” writing down an example would quickly become too broad since you‘ve obviously not yet invested any time to read about ε-differential privacy and I surely don’t want to write a book explaining everything (incl. notations) from scratch. But the pointers (links) I have provided should definitely help you get started on your quest for knowledge.